# plot groups in different figures with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example:

```
require(ggplot2)

aa <- data.frame(date = runif(3,1,100),Change = runif(3,1,100))

bb <- data.frame(date = runif(3,1,100),Change = runif(3,1,100))

dd <- rbind(aa,bb)
dd$site <- c("aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","bb")
```

Is it possible to produce 2 figures in the same document where figure 1 should be those sites that correspond to sites == 'aa' and the second figure should be those sites that correspond to sites == 'bb'?

I have tried to generate the figures within a loop but nothing seems to be plotted in the pdf:

```
nams <- ("aa","bb")

pdf("plots.pdf",width = 6,height = 6, paper='A4',family = "Times")
for (i in 1:2){
  dd2 <- dd[dd$site == nams[i],]

  ggplot(dd,aes(date,Change)) +
    geom_line()
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Why not use `facets`? `ggplot(dd, aes(date, Change)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(site~.)`

Comment: This is just an example code, my real data has over 200 sites, thus i need different plots, i cant realistically use facets for that.

Comment: Do you want multiple plots in the same window or a loop to plot each group individually?  If the former, [look here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `print` with the plot to output it:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  dd2 <- dd[dd$site == nams[i],]

  print(ggplot(dd, aes(date, Change)) +
    geom_line()
  )
}
```